# Flask understand multiple returns in file upload example

Tags: python, flask, syntax

I just started looking into flask and playing around with file uploads but there is something I cannot wrap my head around.

In the documentation example that I basically adapted, we have

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

I do not understand the syntax, for me it seems like there are two return statements which are both executed. For example, if the file is properly chosen and is an allowed file, the file is saved and the user gets redirected in his browser to a url: /?filename=*selected_file* by the `return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))` and then afterwards there is another return which basically renders html to be shown to the user.

From my playing around it seems like both statements are executed and omitting the last one will lead to python complaining that there is no return for the view function.

I am lost on why the function is not exited after the first return executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look like both returns are executed one after the other, but that's because `upload_file` is called twice per upload - once with a GET to render the upload form and once with a POST to do whatever happens after file upload.

The function does indeed exit after the first return much like any other Python program.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it seems I do not understand at all how flask works. How does it actually know it has to call upload_file()? Why is there a GET involved when I only want to post a file?

Comment: The `@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` decorator above the function tells Flask that this function servers that route for these methods. You could split it into `@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])` for a `render_upload_form` function and a `@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])` for a `upload_file` function, thereby dispensing with the big if statement and making the intention clearer.